# Can I run C written in NetBeans on Ubuntu in the Windows NetBeans IDE?

Tags: netbeans, cross-compiling

I have some C code written using the NetBeans editor in Ubuntu 10.04 LTS.

Would I be able to run this on a Windows 7 system without any problems, using the same Windows NetBeans IDE?

Answer (score 0):

**In short no.** (... there are some work arounds)

**On the Linux Side**
Netbeans installed on Ubuntu, by default, will compile this using GCC, and compile it to run on Linux.

**On the Windows Side**
If you basically copied your Ubuntu-Netbeans project in Netbeans for Windows, Netbeans on windows will need to be pointed towards a tool chain. By default, Netbeans looks for the GNU tool chain.
I personally have not been able to get Netbeans to play with the latest Windows SDK packages, so the simple act compiling the same C code on two different platforms with the same IDE is a little tricky. You will see alot of people say to Install GCC on windows, use Cygwin, MinGW, ect.

Keep in mind, **Netbeans** has no affect on the final compiled product of your code, that is up to the compiler being used in the background.